# PHP timed script execution

Tags: php, email, execution, timed

I am not quite sure how to put my question into words, but this is what I am trying to build. I want to send email using PHPMailer through my gmail account. Now, Gmail has a limit of 500 emails in one day. Another thing to consider is, when you send a bulk email at once, there is a chance that my email is sent back to me, as my bulk email is considered to be a spam. I have around 200 in my contact list. So a limit of 500 is not a problem. Now my question is, is there any native PHP function that will only execute the send function of PHPMailer in a certain amount of time duration? What I want to do is, I want to send 10 emails from my contact list every 30mins.. So if I have 200 in my contact list, there is an interval of 30 mins in every 10 contacts until I send the email to everyone. I have no problems creating the email script using PHPMailer. I just need to know if there is a way in PHP to 'time' the execution of my functions. I would appreciate any kinds of help. Thank you!

Comment: No, but you could build a simple queue and use something like a cron job to  trigger a php script to work on that.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it. Do you know of any other solution for Windows OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should really look for [third party solutions](https://www.google.si/search?q=send%20bulk%20email&rlz=1C1ASUM_enSI731SI735&oq=send%20bulk%20email&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2582j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Sending bulk emails via Gmail or any other provider will create problems for you.

I am using [MailGun](https://www.mailgun.com/) (with 200 mails you can use FREE version) for years and it does the job.
Don't forget to check [mailgun for PHP](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php).

Comment: This helped me a ton!